# How can I access my raspberry pi following a WiFi SSID name change?

Tags: wifi, ethernet

I was experiencing issues with my broadband so was advised by support to perform a hard reset. Unfortunately this also reset my custom SSID which I believe has cut WiFi connection for my Raspberry Pi 3 and made it inaccessible remotely.

I've been trying to access via an ethernet cable connected between the Pi and my PC. I have set a dedicated IP address via the IPv4 settings based on my ethernet adapter IP, however, when using my usual logins via PuTTY, I recieve a 'gethostbyname: unknown error'.

From the tutorials I've found so far for how to update WiFi logins etc. this seems to be an essential step. Might there be another way to access the pi to update the WiFi settings?

Note: I've been using the Pi as a domoticz setup to monitor and log temperatures for a few months now, I would like to avoid losing that data if at all possible. Thanks for any help!

Comment: Your question is unclear. If you only changed the router there should be no need to change the Pi - just restore the SSID on the router.

Comment: What's the problem to edit `/etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf` and set the new credentials?

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way for Stretch and Buster is to place a new wpa_supplicant.conf file in the /boot of the SD card by mounting it in a PC or Mac.

Then put the card back in the Pi and power on.

By default, the Raspberry Pi OS looks for new WiFi details each time it boots and replaces the old one.

Note, you can not retrieve the old file unless you have a machine that can read the ext4 partition on the SD Card.  If you do need the data then this *MUST* be done before the new file is put on the card and the Pi booted.

As per the original configuration, the file must follow the details described in the [headless set-up here](https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/configuration/wireless/headless.md)

Comment: This Answer is quite misleading. If you change the WiFi network on the Pi (mine can connect to ~10 different networks) this will have ABSOLUTELY NO impact on the data on the SD Card.

Comment: Sorry @Milliways but I have answered the question - the OP has changed the SSID on the router but does not seem to want to change it back (possibly has forgotten it if it was a random string) so I have explained what the OP can do to connect the Pi to the new SSID as per the question `Might there be another way to access the pi to update the WiFi settings?`

Comment: the warning in your 4th paragraph is wrong. Data on the Card will be unaffected.

Comment: The current wpa_supplicant will be overwritten when the Pi boots with a new file in /boot - that's what I mean by that.